# Proving the following statement using Sets Identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The statement goes as follow:

$ B ∩ C ⊆ A ⇒ (C − A) ∩ (B − A) = ∅. $

First, the sign "=>" represents a tautology, no? ( apparently I get it confuse with the 3 bar sign, if you know what I mean).

Second, the fact that it equals to no solution, how do I prove that? Seems to contradict itself, at least to me.

EDIT: apparently necessary edit... Couldn't start the problem because I did not understand the notation. No need to down vote for that, the more people understand a concept properly, the better....

Comment: That symbol means "implies." So if it is true that $ B \cap C \subset A$ *then* $(C − A) \cap (B − A) = \emptyset$. And it is not "equal to no solution." The quantity is equal to the empty set. That simply means that $C-A$ and $B-A$ have no elements in common.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I'm being downvoted, school system barely touches upon mathematical symbol and my discrete math teacher just skipped them.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. If you edit your question to include what you have tried so far, you will not be downvoted. It could also help to clarify your question; are you just confused about the symbols in the statement? Or are you also stuck on proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, the $"\implies"$ symbol means "implies." If you have two statements $P,Q$ and know that $P \implies Q$, then that is to say "If $P$, then $Q$".

The $"\emptyset"$ symbol is the emptyset. It is the set that contains no elements, and is one of the most important sets in all of set theory. The empty set is somewhat analogous to zero, in as far as $S \cup \emptyset = S$ and $S \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$ for any set $S$, just as $x+0 = x$ and $x\cdot 0 = 0$ for any number $x$. The analogy is not perfect since addition and union are not quite the same, nor are multiplication and intersection.

To start this proof, I recommend stating the following:

> Let $A,B,C$ be sets such that $B\cap C\subseteq A$.

We now assume the above is true. Next, let $x \in C-A$. (The $"\in"$ symbol means "in", or "be an element of " just in case you haven't seen it yet.) By definition, $x \in C$ and $x \notin A$. Since $x \notin A$, then $x \notin B\cap C$. Can you proceed from here to show that $x \notin B-A$?

Now let $y \in B-A$ and use similar reasoning to prove that $y \notin C-A$. Once you do that, you will have shown that $B-A$ and $C-A$ have no elements in common. We then say that their intersection is empty. This is expressed mathematically by stating $(B-A)\cap (C-A) = \emptyset$.

Good luck!

Comment: So, I'll copy paste my answer from above ( if you don't mind that is). Would I just need to prove it using an element prove? like this:                     $ { x:(x∈C∧x!∈A)∧(x∈B∧x!∈A) } $                                                         (Sorry for the !∈, easiest way to say not element haha). I can't really simplify further than that as the claim is true that it has not solution has shown. Would one just need to write that down as an answer, or further proof can be done?

Comment: Also, would the empty set be analogous to the zero vector, or a similar train of thought?

Comment: There is more than one way to skin a cat! You can certainly prove this using set builder notation (an element proof as you call it.) Personally I was never fond of those so I opt to do what I did in my answer.  It looks to me like you have not yet established that  x:(x∈C∧x!∈A)∧(x∈B∧x!∈A) is empty. That is, there is no such $x$ satisfying the set statement. Once you do that, you will have completed the proof. Also, if you right click on any math symbols you find on this website, you can choose "show math as $\to$ Tex commands" to see how to use the symbol.

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair I think it is fair to compare the zero vector to the empty set.

Comment: The part where I get stuck is that we've only been taught to do this with "set identities". However it does seem useless to do that because the notation  "⊆" doesn't apply to them.  Therefore, I don't really see how to mathematically ( so let's say step by step) accomplish this problem unless I explain it in a lengthy manner. I do see what is happening though, but only instinctually.

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair Ah, you can get this pretty easy with set identities. 

$$\begin{align}(B-A)\cap (C-A) = (B\cap A^c)\cap(C\cap A^c) \\ = B\cap A^c \cap C  \cap A^c \\ = (B\cap C) \cap A^c \\ = \emptyset\end{align} $$

Comment: I've never gotten that identity ( wasn't given to us by the teacher). I'm assuming $A^c$ represents the set in which B is contained?

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair $A^c$ is the complement of $A$. You could define it as $$\{x:x\notin A\}$$

Comment: Then how does your two last statement ( so the one where you reduced it using distributivity  and the empty set) work in accord? The complementary set of A and B and C doesn't prove empty set, unless I'm seeing this wrong :/ and thanks for your patience with me

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair The idea is that since $B\cap C$ is completely contained inside $A$, then none of $B\cap C$  can "spill" outside of $A$. That is to say that $B\cap C$ and $A^c$ have no elements in common, or $(B\cap C)\cap A^c=\emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $\Rightarrow$ means that for any sets $A,B,C$, if $B \cap C \subseteq A$ then $(C-A)\cap(B-A)=\emptyset$

You want to prove that if $B \cap C$ is a subset of $A$, then the set $(C-A)\cap (B-A)$ is empty. Drawing a Venn diagram to represent the situation might aid your intuition.

For a formal proof you need to prove that $(C-A)\cap(B-A)$ is contained in $\emptyset$, and that $\emptyset$ is contained in $(C-A)\cap(B-A)$.

I give you the following hint: For any sets $E,F$: $E-F=E\cap F^c$.

**Added**: To prove that the sets are equal you need to prove that each set is contained in the other one.

First we prove that $\emptyset \subseteq (C-A)\cap (B-A)$. This is trivial since the implication $p \rightarrow q$ is true when $p$ is false, in particular the proposition:

$$\forall x, x\in \emptyset \rightarrow x \in (C-A)\cap(B-A)$$

is true, hence $\emptyset \subseteq (C-A)\cap (B-A)$

Now we prove the other inclusion. Take $x \in (C-A) \cap (B-A)$, this means $(x \in C \wedge x \not \in A)\wedge(x \in B \wedge x \not \in A)$, which gives, by De Morgan laws: $x \in (B\cap C) \wedge x \not \in A$, and since $B \cap C \subseteq A$ we deduce $x \in A \wedge x \not \in A$, this is $x \in \emptyset$. This last step is the definition of the empty set in some books. You can also view it like this: given a proposition $p$ which is false (in this case $x \in A \wedge x \not \in A$), then the conditional $p \rightarrow q$ is true.

Comment: Intuitively, I can see it ( using the venn diagram did help thank you !). I do see that B and C intersect and therefore have  x's in common. and they are both part of A, therefore doing C-A is not possible because every x of C is part of A. However, for a formal proof, wouldn't I need to start on the LHS of the equation?

Comment: Would I just need to prove it using an element prove? like this:                                  $ { x: ( x ∈ C  ∧  x !∈  A ) ∧ (x ∈ B  ∧ x  !∈ A) } $ (Sorry for the !∈, easiest way to say not element haha). I can't really simplify further than that as the claim is true that it has not solution has shown. Would one just need to write that down as an answer, or further proof can be done?

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair See my edit. Does that help? Also the MathJax code for negating something is \not [something], in particular \not \in gives $\not \in$